# Number of different strings having specified number of AB permutations

Tags: dynamic-programming, combinatorics

Given four numbers NAA, NAB, NBA, NBB each of them are less or equal to 10^5.

It is needed to the find number of different strings that contain only AB characters and contain:

- exactly NAA occurences of "AA";
- exactly NAB occurence of "AB";
- exactly NBA occurences of "BA";
- exactly NBB occurence of "BB".

I know only brute force solution. 
Could you please give me some hint or advice how to do it faster?

Comment: What are you saying in comment? Please explain through example.

Comment: From the information you have you can determine the number of consecutive runs of "A"s, resp. "B"s. So, you take ABABA... and BABABA.. as starting point and than calculate how many ways there are to inflate the sequence. Google for integer partitions. Always keep in mind that you don't need to construct the sequences to count them ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use two 5-dimensional DP table with state of cell defined as :

```
tableA[N][AA][BB][AB][BA] = no. of strings of length N ending at 'A' having AA times "AA", BB times "BB", AB times "AB" and BA times "BA" and
tableB[N][AA][BB][AB][BA] = no. of strings of length N ending at 'B' having AA times "AA", BB times "BB", AB times "AB" and BA times "BA"
```

Now you can use following state-transition rules to fill the table:

```
tableA[N][AA][BB][AB][BA] = tableA[N-1][AA-1][BB][AB][BA] + tableB[N-1][AA][BB][AB][BA-1] and
tableB[N][AA][BB][AB][BA] = tableA[N-1][AA][BB][AB-1][BA] + tableB[N-1][AA][BB-1][AB][BA]
```

Use appropriate base cases and finally retrieve answer:

```
answer = tableA[AB][NAA][NBB][NAB][NBA] + tableB[AB][NAA][NBB][NAB][NBA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am afraid that this solution won't work because of usage huge amount of memory.

Comment: I believe that soon I'll find the answer and I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

So, time for the answer.

Given a string you can do the following transformations without changing N<sub>AB</sub> and N<sub>BA</sub>

- AA -> A
- A -> AA
- BB -> B
- B -> BB

So, we can arrive at any valid string by starting from a string that contains neither AA nor BB by "inflation".

#### Inflating

Lets assume we have a string without AA and BB substrings that has the correct number of ABs and BAs.

Let N<sub>A</sub> the number of As and N<sub>B</sub> the number of Bs in that string (calculation of these are shown below).

Than we need to distribute N<sub>AA</sub> As to N<sub>A</sub> places. There are binom(N<sub>AA</sub>+N<sub>A</sub>-1, N<sub>A</sub>-1) ways to do that (look up integer [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics))). There are also binom(N<sub>BB</sub>+N<sub>B</sub>-1, N<sub>B</sub>-1) possibilities to place the additional Bs. Because insertion of As and Bs is independant we can simply multiply the numbers to get all possibilities.

#### Calculating the actual result

There are four cases to consider:

1. N<sub>AB</sub> = N<sub>BA</sub>+1: The string starts with A and ends with B. N<sub>A</sub>=N<sub>B</sub>=N<sub>AB</sub>

   So, N = binom(N<sub>AA</sub>+N<sub>AB</sub>-1, N<sub>AB</sub>-1) * binom(N<sub>BB</sub>+N<sub>AB</sub>-1, N<sub>AB</sub>-1)
2. N<sub>AB</sub>+1 = N<sub>BA</sub>: Same as above just excchange A and B everywhere
3. N<sub>AB</sub> = N<sub>BA</sub>:
   The string either begins with A and ends with A or begins with B and ends with B. So there are two possibilities that need to be added.

   1. String starts with A gives N<sub>A</sub>=N<sub>AB</sub>+1  and N<sub>B</sub>=N<sub>AB</sub>
   2. String starts with B gives N<sub>A</sub>=N<sub>AB</sub>  and N<sub>B</sub>=N<sub>AB</sub>+1

   So, N = binom(N<sub>AA</sub>+N<sub>AB</sub>, N<sub>AB</sub>)*binom(N<sub>BB</sub>+N<sub>AB</sub>-1, N<sub>AB</sub>-1)

   + binom(N<sub>AA</sub>+N<sub>AB</sub>-1, N<sub>AB</sub>-1)*binom(N<sub>BB</sub>+N<sub>AB</sub>, N<sub>AB</sub>)
4. For all other pairs of N<sub>AB</sub> and N<sub>BA</sub>: N=0.

I hope, I have got all the "-1"s right. And sorry for the bad layout.